# Is it possible to cluster CSS selectors with the same root?

Tags: css, sass

If I have code like:

```
.container .header {...}
.container .content p {...}
.container .button-wrapper .button {...}
.container .footer {...}
```

Can all these selectors be clustered e.g. like that with normal CSS?

```
.container {
   .header {...}
   .content p {...}
   .button-wrapper .button {...}
   .footer {...}
}
```

... or would I have to use Sass to do this?

Comment: Yeah, you should use SASS.

Comment: Yeah, using LESS or SASS or other CSS preprocessors

Comment: okay, thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. To do this you must use some of CSS preprocessors like SASS, LESS, SCSS..